# AngularJs call service function from controller undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I'm trying to call a function from my dataservice factory but it throws an error 
**Cannot read property 'login' of undefined**

*Here is my dataservice factory*

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  // dataservice factory
 angular
.module('app')
.factory('dataservice', dataservice);

 dataservice.$inject = ['$http'];

 function dataservice($http) {

  return {
    login  : login
  }


function login(username, password, callback) {
    $http.post('/data', { username: username, password: password })
        .success(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
       });
    }  
 }
})();
```

*Here is my controller*

```
(function(){

'use strict';

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('TestController', TestController);

TestController.$inject = ['dataservice'];

function TestController(dataservice) { 

  var vm = this;

  vm.login = login;



function login() {
console.log('is this called?');
    vm.loading = true;
    dataservice.login(vm.username, vm.password, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
 }

 }
})();
```

*login function it is called when i press login from view , since i get:* ***is this called?*** *in my console*.

Comment: missing a } after function data service

Comment: I checked syntax and it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected your example to more common and readable syntax. [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EternalLight/ahoqoo3b/1/) to see it in action.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    // dataservice factory
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.factory('dataservice', ['$http', function ($http) {

        function login(username, password, callback) {
            console.log('Login in dataservice...');
            $http.post('/data', {username: username, password: password})
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.warn(error);
                });
        }

        return {
            login: login
        };

    }]);

    app.controller('TestController', ['dataservice', function (dataservice) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.login = login;
        function login() {
            console.log('is this called?');
            vm.loading = true;
            dataservice.login(vm.username, vm.password, function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
        }
    }]);
})
();
```

1. You should pass second argument to app.module as an empty array (if you have no dependencies on other modules)
2. Use $http.then because .success is depricated.
3. Pass second argument to app.factory or app.controller as an array with a list of dependencies and the function at last. In your example, you didn't inject any dependencies because TestController.$inject = ['dataservice']; was running too late.

Comment: I do not know what was my problem , but It worked now without changes. Anyway thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to right the callback in a `then` block

```
function login() {
    console.log('is this called?');
    vm.loading = true;
    dataservice.login(vm.username, vm.password).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }, function(error){
    });
 }
```

This is the correct syntax.

Also you can use this service syntax

```
   function login(){
        var d = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/data',
            data:{
                username : username,
                password : password
            }
        }).success(function(response){
            d.resolve(response);
        }).error(function(response){
            d.reject(response);
        });
        return d.promise;
    }
```

Comment: I tried using this code but i got the same error **Cannot read property 'login' of undefined** , I copied your service and controller function . Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: can you create a fiddle or plunkr, because i don't see any reason to get a error like undefined method..

Comment: you are getting your service as undefined, see if it is added in `index.html` and defined properly?

Comment: I minify my code in a single file , and from index.html file is called login function that points to login() in controller. Until here , it is okay since i it prints my console.log line . When it should call dataservice function it throws an error. I have also tried using a simple function from dataservice , but I still get the same error **Cannot read property '(function name)' of undefined**

Comment: don't use $q when $http already return a promise, just return the $http.